# I need get second group in regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't know how to get a second group given a string. Now [I have Full Watch and Group 1(not completely)](https://regex101.com/r/Ve7B78/3) with `(?:<p>)?@preview\((.*)\)(?:<\/p>)?`

Example strings:

```
@preview(example-component/example-component)
<p>@preview(example-component/example-component)</p>
@preview(example-component/example-component, title="sadad" text="asd")
@preview(example-component/example-component, title="sadad" text="asd" )
```

Full match:

```
@preview(example-component/example-component)
```

Or

```
<p>@preview(example-component/example-component)</p>
```

Or

```
@preview(example-component/example-component, title="sadad" text="asd")
```

Group 1:

```
example-component/example-component
```

Group 2:

```
title="sadad" text="asd"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression has only one matching group which matches everything inside the `()`, you just need to split it into 2 groups based on coma.

```
(?:<p>)?@preview\((.*?)(?:,\s*(.*?))?\)(?:<\/p>)?
```

I changed `(.*)` to `(.*?)(?:,\s*(.*?))?`

`(.*?)` Non greedy all selector to match everything, non greedy makes it stop at the first coma it found

`(?:,\s*(.*?))?` Non capturing group to capture everything after the previous group including `,` to mark it as optional using `?`

`(.*?)` Second non greedy all selector captures everything after `,` excluding any spaces

https://regex101.com/r/c5qOFn/1

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\(([^,)]+)(?:,\s*([^)]+))?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cDzsIS/1/).

---

More verbose, this is

```
\(              # match a "(" literally
    ([^,)]+)    # not a comma nor a ) -> group 1
    (?:,\s*     # a non-capturing group, followed by whitespaces
        ([^)]+) # not a ) -> group 2
    )?          # thw whole term is optional
```

IN `JavaScript`:

```js
let strings = ['@preview(example-component/example-component)',
'<p>@preview(example-component/example-component)</p>',
'@preview(example-component/example-component, title="sadad" text="asd")',
'@preview(example-component/example-component, title="sadad" text="asd" )'];

let rx = /\(([^,)]+)(?:,\s*([^)]+))?/;

strings.forEach(function(item) {
    let m = item.match(rx);
    if (typeof(m[2]) !== "undefined") {
        console.log(m[2]);
    }
});
```